# csvsimple respect dollar not working

Tags: csvsimple

I'm using csvsimple to import some columns from a csv file into a tabular environment. The CSV file contains a column where all the values are dollar amounts, so just including it directly gives errors like the following:

- `Extra }, or forgotten $. ...tNum & \Reference & \UnitPriceAtOneKUnits}`
- `Missing $ inserted. ...tNum & \Reference & \UnitPriceAtOneKUnits}`
- `Missing } inserted. ...tNum & \Reference & \UnitPriceAtOneKUnits}`

After reading through the [manual for csvsimple](https://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/csvsimple/csvsimple.pdf), I found there are `respect` commands that should be able to be added. However it doesn't seem to respect either the `respect dollar` or `respect all` options. I've also tried `respect dollar=true`, `respect all=true`, `/csv/respect dollar=true`, and `/csv/respect all=true`. I don't mind if it respects all since I'm not planning on putting LaTeX in any of the fields - I just want it to display the data for the selected columns.

Here is the code that is currently not working:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in,bottom=1in,top=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{c|l|l|l|r}%
        \bfseries Qty & \bfseries Part Description & \bfseries Manufacturer Part \# & \bfseries Reference & \bfseries Unit Price At 1K Units
        \csvreader[respect dollar,head to column names,separator=pipe]{BOM.csv}{}%
        {\\\hline\Qty & \PartDescription & \ManufacturerPartNum & \Reference & \UnitPriceAtOneKUnits}%
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Here is some sample data for the csv file (with only revelant columns):

```
Qty|PartDescription|ManufacturerPartNum|Reference|UnitPriceAtOneKUnits
5|Part 1|Option|Z1,Z2,Z3| $0.003
1|Part 2|Option|D1,D2,D3,D4| $0.004 
2|Part 3|Option|U1,U2,U3,U4| $0.008
```

Any help would be appreciated.

**Software Versions:**

- TeXStudio 2.12.6
- MiKTeX 2.9.6350
- csvsimple 1.21

Comment: Welcome to TeX-SE! Try replacing all `$` in your cvs file by `\$`, i.e. add a backslash. A `$` is a special character in LaTeX that starts/ends math mode.

Comment: I get that that is a possible solution, however isn't `respect dollar` supposed to make it so you don't have to do that?

Comment: Maybe. To check it would be great if you could post a complete minimal working example that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Ok, I updated it.

Comment: Seems to be a bug for me. Can you please write an bug report for the maintainer?

Comment: Ok, I submitted a bug report to the github. I'll report back if they respond. For now I'm just going to escape them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's certainly a bug, a workaround could be to deactivate the `$` sign before the table and reactivate it after.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in,bottom=1in,top=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{csvsimple}

% this code is only to create BOM.csv, you don't need it:
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{BOM.csv}
Qty|PartDescription|ManufacturerPartNum|Reference|UnitPriceAtOneKUnits
5|Part 1|Option|Z1,Z2,Z3| $0.003
1|Part 2|Option|D1,D2,D3,D4| $0.004
2|Part 3|Option|U1,U2,U3,U4| $0.008
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
Before the table \$ works as usual $a+b$
\catcode`\$=12% deactivate $ sign
\begin{table}[h]
    \begin{tabular}{c|l|l|l|r}%
        \bfseries Qty & \bfseries Part Description & \bfseries Manufacturer Part \# & \bfseries Reference & \bfseries Unit Price At 1K Units
        \csvreader[
        head to column names,separator=pipe]{BOM.csv}{}%
        {\\\hline\Qty & \PartDescription & \ManufacturerPartNum & \Reference & \UnitPriceAtOneKUnits}%
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\catcode`\$=3% reactivate $ sign

After the table \$ works as usual $a+b$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oops, yeah I forgot to swap those to pipes when I updated the question. That deactivating and reactivating seems like just the trick!

Answer (score 3):

Actually, `respect dollar` also sets the `\catcode` of `$` to `12` at the begin of `\csvreader`. But this setting gets lost from one cell of the table to the next, because cell contents are inside a TeX group.

Therefore, `$` has to be deactivated before the table starts. CarLaTeX showed one way to do it.

The other way is to use the built-in tabular functions from `csvsimple`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper,landscape]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in,bottom=1in,top=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\begin{document}
  \begin{table}[h]
    \csvreader[respect dollar,head to column names,separator=pipe,
      tabular={c|l|l|l|r},
      table head={\bfseries Qty & \bfseries Part Description & \bfseries Manufacturer Part \# & \bfseries Reference & \bfseries Unit Price At 1K Units\\\hline},
      late after line=\\\hline,
      late after last line=,
    ]{BOM.csv}{}%
    {\Qty & \PartDescription & \ManufacturerPartNum & \Reference & \UnitPriceAtOneKUnits}%
  \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Here, `respect dollar` works for the whole table and not for the first line only.